# Goals & Funnels

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I have only page (default.aspx) in my site and i want to configure that page in Google analytics's goals & funnel . can anyone help me that what i have to do to configure to achieve goal ?

Regards,
Sagar

Comment: With only one page, a funnel doesn't make sense...

Comment: @MauricioScheffer it actually does. Maybe not from the point Google sees funnel where each step must be an url, but you might have an action in that page which you want to track (step by step).

Answer (score 2):

You can have a single dynamic page with a number of steps. The key to logging each step with GA is to call the urchinTracker method and pass the URL you want that hit to be recorded as.

Once you control the hits GA records for each step you can add the final page as the goal and the intermediate pages in the funnel.

We have a 3 step registration process served from a single ASPX page (`/registration/register.aspx)`. I output the following GA code on the page, incrementing the step number each time;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _uacct = "UA-1234567-1";
    urchinTracker('/registration/Step1.html');
</script>
```

On our final page I redirect to my acknowledgement.aspx page and call GA normally

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _uacct = "UA-1234567-1";
    urchinTracker();
</script>
```

The Goal Funnel is then;

```
/register/acknowledgement.aspx

/registration/Step1.html
/registration/Step2.html
/registration/Step3.html
```

Maybe Google explain it better; https://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55514&hl=en_US&utm_id=ad

Comment: This is with the much older version of Google Analytics so there mayeb a different way with the newer API.

Answer (score 1):

You need two pages-- that's what I did because it was easy.  Google analytics records success as visiting a particular page.  The number of times people visit your landing page feeds into your click through rate.  The number of times people click through and do at least one more click to the conversion page feeds into your conversion rate.

If you really need a one page solution, you might be able to add a button and postback event, say

```
protected MyButtonClick(...)
{
   Page.Controls.Add(new literal("...google's conversion widget code...")
}
```

But the URL would still be the same from google's standpoint.  The next step would be trying to do URL rewriting with a HTTP Handler to simulate multiple pages with just one aspx page behind it all.